# findViewById() Returns Null View Created From Databinding

Tags: android, kotlin

For some reason when I use findFragmentById() to reference a SeekBar view created with a databinding it returns a null object. How can I get a reference for this view, please?

This is my seekBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </SeekBar>
</layout>
```

This is my class:

```
open class UtilClass(activity: Activity) {
...
val seekBar = activity.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
..
}
```

The seekbar is inflated using DataBindingUtil in its own Fragment:

```
class SeekBarFragment(): Fragment {
...
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: SeekbarBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.seekbar, container, false)
...
}
```

UtilClass is instantiated here:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mUtilClass: UtilClass
....
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mUtilClass = UtilClass(requireActivity())
    retainInstance = true

    var fm = fragmentManager
    var fragment: Fragment? = fm!!.findFragmentById(R.id.seek_container)

    if (fragment == null) {

        fragment = SeekBarFragment.newInstance()

        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.seek_container, fragment)
            .commit()
            }
}
```

Binding is created here:

```
class SeekBarFragment: Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): SeekBarFragment {
        return SeekBarFragment()
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val binding: SeekbarBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.seekbar, container, false)
...
}
```

Comment: Where is your UtilClass instantiated?

Comment: Sorry I am adding it to the main question

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the parent layout view.

```java
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        var v: View =inflater.inflate(R.layout.seekbar, container, false)
        var seekbar=v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar)

return v

}
```

Comment: but I created the view with a databinding: val binding: SeekbarBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.seekbar, container, false)

Answer (score 0):

In this case view is not tied to activity.

> Finds a view that was identified by the {@code android:id} XML attribute * that was processed in {@link #onCreate}.

view is available on the Fragment,
store binding as a global variable in SeekBarFragment class lateint var binding: SeekbarBinding

when ever you need a specific view from binding, Please do as following

```js
open class UtilClass(binding: ViewDataBinding) {
...

val seekBar = binding.root.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)?.apply{bar->
bar.
}
}
```

In addition use kotlin extension to simplify the code

```js
protected fun ViewDataBinding.getSeekBar(@IdRes id: Int): SeekBar? {
        root.findViewById<SeekBar>(id)?.apply {
            return this
        }
        return null
    }
```

Please try below line, you are lucky if it works!!

> activity?.supportFragmentManager?.fragments?.firstOrNull()?.view?.findViewById(R.id.seekBar)